# as_tsibble(id(), index ()) setting Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'xxx' not found

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am learning using tsibble and fable to do forecasting. 
first difficulty here is trying to reform my dataset into tsibble formate by using

```
as_tsibble(
    key=id (product |cate, store), index= date)
```

(I am following the video called:tsibble: Tidy data structures to support exploration and modeling of temporal-context data, on youtube)

but, I got the error:

> Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'product' not found

I do have the product column in my dataset: here are my code for your info

```
safe_div <- function(upr, lwr) if_else(lwr == 0, 0, upr/lwr)

df_s <- df %>% 
  select(date=Datum, store=ButiN, cate=KategoriNM, product=PluId, quan=Styck, sales=Sales) %>%
  mutate(price= round(safe_div(sales,quan), 2)) %>% 
  as_tibble()

df_s %>% as_tsibble(
    key=id (product |cate, store), index= date)
```

not sure where I get wrong. any suggestion will be appriciated

here is the screeshot of df_s dataset for your info
[image]

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example with `dput`

Comment: if i run df_s %>% as_tsibble(
    key=id (product, store), index= date) . , seems work(which means I can not indicate the product under the category hierarchy )

Comment: Do you know if `tsibble` uses `|`, `,` to separate the variables.  Check if `df_s %>% as_tsibble(key = id(product), index = date)`

Comment: Hi akrun, sorry, I am not sure what do you mean. did not use dput function before.  is there any chance I can just send or attache an excel or CSV file?

Comment: Its okay.  My doubt is with the usage of `as_tsibble`.  I checked the documentation, couldn't find the way in which you used `|` and `,`

Comment: Yes. i follow the vedio from Earo Wang. and in the vedio she has the example use |: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6yRmbulxUM, use the time 6:29 then you see the example

Comment: The nesting operator  `|`  has been removed from the key specification since v0.6.0. We think that the nesting and crossing is more suitable for the forecasting reconciliation stage.